# Is there a way to configure git to clone with --filter=blob:none by default?

Tags: git, git-clone

After reading the Github Blog Post [Get up to speed with partial clone and shallow clone](https://github.blog/2020-12-21-get-up-to-speed-with-partial-clone-and-shallow-clone/), I would like to have `git clone` use `--filter=blob:none` by default to reduce the time and size required by `git clone`.

I haven't been able to find a way to achieve this.
I was hoping for something like `git config --global clone.filter=blob:none` but as far as I was able to find no such config option is currently recognized by git.

I have currently defined a `blobless-clone` alias `git config --global alias.blobless-clone 'clone --filter=blob:none'`, but I would preferer the normal `clone` command to be changed instead.
So that I don't accidentally do a full clone, especially as git integrations for example my IDE won't know about the alias.

I noticed that `git-rev-list` having a `--no-filter` option to clear previous filters while `git clone` does not appear to have such an option, as such it would not be possible to do a normal clone while a default filter is configured. But that would be fine with me.